# How to define a new C type in CDT Java API

Tags: java, eclipse-cdt

I work on a script editor and added C block using GPPLanguage class and auto-detected C keywords using ICLanguageKeywords CDT API

I want to define new C types besides the builtin types (int ,char, ... etc)

How could I do this?

```
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.ast.gnu.cpp.GPPLanguage;
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.model.ICLanguageKeywords;

public class KWTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ICLanguageKeywords fKeywords = GPPLanguage.getDefault();
        String[] types = fKeywords.getBuiltinTypes();
        ArrayList<String> typesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(types));
        for (int i = 0; i < typesList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(typesList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

The output is: 
bool 
char 
char16_t 
char32_t 
double 
float
int 
long 
short 
signed 
unsigned 
void 
wchar_t

I want to define other types e.g. uint64_t (unsigned long long)

Comment: It's not clear from the question how you're *using* the `ICLanguageKeywords`. Can you provide some more details? Also note that `GPPLanguage` is for C++ (and that's why you see some C++-specific built-in types like `char16_t` in the list). If you want C, use `GCCLanguage`.